# How to calculate $\sin\frac{2\pi}{13}-\sin\frac{5\pi}{13}+\sin\frac{6\pi}{13}$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to calculate this trigonometric function?
> $$\sin\frac{2\pi}{13}-\sin\frac{5\pi}{13}+\sin\frac{6\pi}{13}$$

I think this function is related to $x^{26}=-1$.

This Problem is provided by Tieba(Chinese facebook) users.

Comment: Calculator says around 0.5224 so probably not a good answer.

Comment: The number agrees with $(2+\tfrac6{13}\sqrt{13})^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @g.kov Thank you sir,you are right!!!Can you share you procedure with us?

Comment: This is just the output 
from the [inverse calculator](http://www.mrob.com/pub/ries).
It also equals to $\cos\tfrac{9\pi}{26}-\cos\tfrac{3\pi}{26}+\cos\tfrac{\pi}{26}$,
and the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridecagon) 
suggests that a regular tridecagon can be constructed using an angle trisector, 
so most probably the angle trisection is the key to solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I don't see any other way other than solving and approximating later. Also, your idea about x^26=−1 doesn't work, its roots are not exactly this type.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is $$  \sqrt{\frac{13 - 3 \sqrt{13}}{8}   } $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

If
$$ \alpha = e^{2 \pi i/13}  $$
we can confirm, without tears, that
$$  x = \alpha + \alpha^3 + \alpha^9$$
satisfies
$$  x^4 + x^3 + 2 x^2 - 4x +3 = 0$$

see page 13 of Reuschle (1875)
[image]

Next factored
$$ \left(x^2 + \frac{1+ \sqrt{13}}{2 } x +  \frac{5+ \sqrt{13}}{2 }\right)  \left(x^2 + \frac{1- \sqrt{13}}{2 } x +  \frac{5- \sqrt{13}}{2 }\right)   $$
while your  number is the imaginary part of $x$

Your number is $$  \sqrt{\frac{13 - 3 \sqrt{13}}{8}   } $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Recalling
$ \alpha = e^{2 \pi i/13}  ,$
$$ y = a^2 + a^5 + a^6 $$ also satisfies
$$ y^4 + y^3 + 2 y^2 - 4y+3 = 0 $$

The imaginary part of $y$ is $$  \sqrt{\frac{13 + 3 \sqrt{13}}{8}   } $$

Answer (score 1):

With the shorthands $a=\frac\pi{13}$,

$$p=\cos2a+\cos6a+\cos8a, \>\>\>\>\>
q=\cos4a+\cos10a+\cos12a$$
and the fact
$$p+q=\sum_{k=1}^6 \cos2ka = Re \sum_{k=1}^6 e^{i2ka} =-\frac12$$
it is straightforward to verify that $pq =\frac32(p+q)=-\frac34
$, which lead to
$$p= \frac14(\sqrt{13}-1),\>\>\>\>\>q= -\frac14(\sqrt{13}+1)$$
Then, use $2\sin x \sin y= \cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y)$ to express

$$\left( \sin2a-\sin5a+\sin6a\right)^2= \frac32 +\frac12q -p
$$
and plug in the values for $p$ and $q$ to obtain

$$\sin2a-\sin5a+\sin6a = \sqrt{\frac{13-3\sqrt{13}}8}
$$